# In thymeleaf , how can I show data when not in html tag

Tags: html, thymeleaf

This is my code, what can I do that for show the variable in tag p and after tag span ?

```
 <p> <span>data：</span> [[${ dto.data } ]]</p>
```

And the result like this

```
 <p> <span>data：</span>  mydata </p>
```

Comment: Use th:inline="text"

Comment: Why have you commented on your own question?

Comment: I found this solution after asked this question . so I commented for myself. And thank you!~